# How to pass data from Java code to R code periodically

Tags: java, r, jri, rserve

I have java code which is collecting about 100 events per minute. I have to pass these events to R code (in turn R code may call back to my java code). I donot like to send them in batches and would like to hand over the messages to R code as soon as they are collected.
1)based on my understanding so far, RServe can help Java code call R code. Can I use RServe also for callback to my Java code from R
2)Can JRI instead serve my purpose where Java code can call R and R in turn can do callback to Java
3)say I want to write my 100 events to file (not serialization, just write them as text). Is there a package in R that can act as file watcher which gets called as soon as file is modified (similar to java.nio.FileWatch)

what is the recommended approach given some of above possible ways of doing it. I am not looking for one time call, but it is going to be about 100 R calls from java to R (with possible callbacks). thanks for looking into this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using files for exchanging data between Java and R code.
Bridging with other technologies between java and R seemed to be expensive for streaming data